# The login doesn't show a username anymore

Tags: users

I can't login into my Drupal anymore and I'm not sure why.
I've got the BOTCHA Spam Prevention module and commerce (enabled with anonymous checkout).
Now my login looks like this:
[image: Login without username]
I can't create a new user:
"the field username is required"
and I can't request my password (there is no username/email field).

I repaired the session table already. Tried several browsers and computers and the admin account has the User ID 1.

Don't know how I can get back into my Drupal :-S
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Dou you have drush installed?

Comment: No .. but would the help in a way? It would be possible.

Comment: you could disable the module that causing the issue easily using drush command `drush dis modulename`

Comment: Do you see html of username textfield in html source of page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to disable the module that causing the problem. There are multiple ways of doing that.

#### Using Drush

> `drush dis modulename`

#### Database hack

In the system table find the module and set its status to 0

> `UPDATE {system} SET status=0 WHERE name='modulename'`

Comment: I installed drush and disable spamicide.
That was the mean one which blew my login.

Comment: Glad to hear that you could solve your problem.